# Truffle, EIP 170 - Contract Couldn't Be Stored Please Check Your Gas Amount

Tags: contract-development, truffle, eip170

I have been developing my contracts using the truffle framework. Everything has been fine, but now when running tests for one of my contracts I am getting the error `The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.` I'd like to reference EIP-170 as I haven't seen other questions regarding this error reference it. 
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md

There is in fact a hard limit on the size of contracts. How can I determine if my contract exceeds the size set forth in EIP 170, if it is a problem with truffle, or if it is a problem with my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the size of your contracts in bytes with:

```
grep \"bytecode\" build/contracts/* | awk '{print $1 " " length($3)/2}'
```

According to EIP 170 (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md) if contract bytecode is bigger than 24576 bytes (`0x6000` bytes), contract creation fails with an out of gas error.

See also https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/960.